# php mysql bit fields

Tags: php, mysql

Strange, i am using apache + php with windows. php processed mysql bit fields as number:
it's work correct;

```
$b = $row['bit_field'] 
if ($b == 1) {
  echo 'ok';
}
```

with centos and php 5.3.3 './configure' '--with-mysql' '--with-mcrypt' '--enable-mbstring' '--with-imap' '--with-kerberos' '--with-imap-ssl' '--with-libjpeg' '--with-libpng' '--with-gd'

i need

```
$b = $row['bit_field'] 
if (ord($b) == 1) {
  echo 'ok';
}
```

What option changing it?

--
Thanx

Comment: What does `$row["bit_field"]` contain?

Comment: *"Strange, I am using apache + php with windows."* - Indeed. :-)

Comment: @Tomalak pah. It's not 1999 anymore. Apache + Win work like a charm :)

Comment: @Pekka: I did not say it would not work. :-)

Comment: I have the exact problem, under Linux/php I have to use ord($row['bit_field']) to get a 0 or 1 value, while for windows, I can simply use $row['bit_field']. I'm using the same MySQL server.

Answer (score 5):

If the field you're dealing with is indeed a bit field, then surely you should be using the bit field operators to test what bits are set in the value?

```
if ($b & 0X1) { echo ('Least significant bit in byte set'); }
if ($b & 0X80) { echo ('Most significant bit in byte set'); }
if ($b & 0X80000000) { echo ('Most significant bit in 32 bit word set'); }
```

You can use these to check individual bits in a bit field regardless of the values of the other bits.